# Flash can't find FLVplayback skin file while running in asp.net mvc view

Tags: asp.net, flash, asp.net-mvc-2, url-routing

Could anyone help me on why FLVPlayback isn't working properly in MVC views?
I think i narrowed it down to the "hard coded" skin url file not being correct.

Where should I put the skin file( e.g. skinOverAllNoCaption.swf)
so that flash can find it?

Or are there any alternative approaches to somehow setting the skin file dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In the same directory as the loaded SWF, or the document loading it - one of the two, if you've not set the URL yourself.

Comment: If I put it in the same directory as the loaded SWF, it just doesn't load.  Hard coding the skin url to a absolute url works, but feels a little wrong. 
The issue I have is solely with MVC views, In which the path just isn't working because of the routing.